# Forwarding responsive emails while retaining media querires

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Is it possible to avoid stripping out media queries when forwarding responsive emails from Outlook or any other email client for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since what you'll forward is the end result of the html, after all queries and styles are processed. Therefore, the final style are "set in stone" and won't be understandable by other mail clients. (Outlook uses proprietary classes and IDs, same with Yahoo, Gmail etc.). Since not every mail client understands media queries, Outlook won't rewrite those into standard CSS  for other mail clients to understand.